# When running mediation analysis with parametric bootstrap in r, receiving error on factor variables but not without bootstrap

Tags: r, regression, interaction, mediation

I am receiving this error message when running a mediation analysis in r using the mediation package:

"Error in model.frame.default(Terms, newdata, na.action = na.action, xlev = object$xlevels) :  factor Race has new levels 4, 5"

I have omitted any na's in my data, and this is only happening for my race and martial status categories that I have included as covariates. This does not happen when bootstrap is set to 'false'. I have double checked that my levels for these categories are set and am unsure of how to fix this error. Thank you in advance.

This are my models:

m_model <- lm(M ~ X + c1 + c2 + c3 + c4 + c5 + c6 + c7 + c8 + c9 + c10, data = thesis)

y_model <- lm(Y ~ M + X + c1 + c2 + c3 + c4 + c5 + c6 + c7 + c8 + c9 + c10, data = thesis)

med.result <- mediate(m_model, y_model, treat = 'X', mediator = 'M', boot = TRUE, sims = 1000, covariates = c('c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4', 'c5', 'c6', 'c7', 'c8', 'c9', 'c10'))

Comment: Purely programming questions are off-topic on Cross Validated; you can read the guidelines [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). You could consider posting your question on Stack Overflow instead. To make it easier to get help, you should provide a minimal reproducible example as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.